# Replace Dash with Space in PHP

Tags: php, string

I currently have this line in my code:

```
<div><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/local/'.$row[website].'-seo-services">'.ucwords($row[website]).'</a></div>
```

And it will display a city name such as this:

```
Puiol-del-piu
```

But what I need is for it to display without the dashes and so that ucwords will capitalize the first letter of each word such as this:

```
Puiol Del Piu
```

It would be great if the code could be confined to this one line because I have a lot more going on with others stuff in the page as well.

Comment: `"one line"` Use functions!

Comment: This regex do the job.
$string = preg_replace("/[\-\]/", " ", $string);

Comment: No need for a regex - str_replace will do the job for less memory, cpu and elapsed time

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
<?php
echo '<div><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/local/'.$row[website].'-seo-services">'.ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$row[website])).'</a></div>';
```

In the above example you can use `str_replace()` to replace hyphens with spaces to create separate words. Then use `ucwords()` to capitalize the newly created words.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Answer (score 72):

This str_replace does the job:

```
$string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);
```

Also, you can make it as a function.

```
function replace_dashes($string) {
    $string = str_replace("-", " ", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Then you call it:

```
$varcity = replace_dashes($row[website]);
<div><a href="http://www.envisionforce.com/local/'.$row[website].'-seo-services">'.ucwords($varcity).'</a></div>
```

Comment: The first two params in your example are swapped from what they should be. Easy fix! Thanks for the examples.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @SteveMeisner, actually not. He want to get rid of the "dashes", replacing them with spaces. That's what the function does.

Comment: Darkeden — you're correct! I read it opposite (probably because I was trying to replace spaces with dashes...). Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

replace dash with space

```
str_replace("-"," ",$row[text])
```

replace space with dash

```
str_replace(" ","-",$row[text])
```

Answer (score 6):

str_replace ('Find what you want to replace', 'Replace with ', 'Your array or string variable');

If you want to replace dash with space, you can use this:

```
str_replace("-"," ",$row[text])
```

If you want to replace space with dash, use this:

```
str_replace(" ","-",$row[text])
```

Use ucwords() to capitalize words.